# linear transformations and projections - doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

suppose that we have **$ T:F^{m}\rightarrow F $** , is a linear transformation , then it is a **$F$**-linear combination of  projection operators , that is ,**$ T=\sum_{1}^{m}a_{i}p_{i} $** where **$p_{i}$** is the projection transformation ?

*I only need a **hint** for the problem not the entire solution as I have been stuck in the start and can't proceed any further but maybe a hint would help me start the solution and may be complete it too !*

Comment: Take the canonical basis of $F^m$ and for $x\in F^m$ write it as a linear combination of the basis elements. Now apply T on x and use its linearity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis.  Given a vector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, note that $p_i(x) = x_i$ and that
$$
T(x) = T(x_1e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n) = x_1 T(e_1) + \cdots + x_n T(e_n).
$$

Comment: well the hint is appreciated but as far as I know , what you posted is much more than a hint , seems like **a solution** !  so a **+1** for it  but please try to be **vague** and not give entire solutions as **"hints"**